# RISC-V Examples Using Pointers

Tags: pointers, assembly, stack, cpu-registers, riscv

I have an engineering assignment where I have to use RISC-V to decide whether or not the first character of a string is capitalized. I'm having trouble finding the first character of my string. (I commented out my if condition)

```
    .data
enterString: .string "Enter a string: "
lowerCaseResult: .string "The first character is a lower-case letter\n"
upperCaseResult: .string "The first character is not a lower-case letter\n"
string: .space 82
    .text
main:
    li a7, 4
    la a0, enterString
    ecall
    
    li a7, 8
    addi a1, zero, 20
    la a0, string
    ecall
    
    la s1, string
    sb a1, 0(s1)
    mv a0, a1
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    
    #slt t0, a0,zero
    ##beq t0, zero, secondCondition
    li a7, 10
    ecall
    
firstCondition:
    li a7, 4
    la a0, lowerCaseResult
    ecall

    li a7, 10
    ecall
    
secondCondition:
    li a7, 4
    la a0, upperCaseResult
    ecall

    li a7, 10
    ecall
```

Any... pointers?

Comment: `sb` is **store** byte. I assume you wanted `lb`.

Comment: @Jester Even with that change, I'm getting a "0x00400038: address out of range 0x00000044" error for ecall. Do I need to allocate memory somehow for that?

Comment: What do you want that `ecall` to do? Note you loaded the first letter which is 0x44 so you seem to have entered something starting with a capital `D`.

Comment: @Jester I wanted ecall to load 0x44 to the a0 register to just print it for now

Comment: That ecall expects a pointer though.